# Hibernate: update entry with changed type

Tags: java, hibernate, crud

I'm dealing with CRUD on a class hierarhy: `Employee->{Manager, Waiter, Chef}` using Spring MVC.
I'm using single table inheritance strategy with a field DTYPE as a discriminator.
Where I am stuck is a situation, when I need to update Waiter -> Manager (not is a case a waiter has been promoted, but just to fix a user's input error!!!) or any other combination of entities.

Hibernate in itself refuses to change the type recorded in DTYPE field, even if I explicitly do:

```
managerDAO.update(manager);
```

where `manager` is an object of `Manager` class with already existing Id (belongning to a Waiter type (DTYPE = "Waiter")) in the DB.

**Now the question is:** How do I correct my user's input mistake which is seemingly pretty simple and prevalent situation? I just need to make former Waiter entry become a Manager entry with the same ID.

I wonder if Hibernate has some tricks to deal with a situation like this? Because I do not want to re-invent a wheel OR find a workaround feeling this should be foreseen by the Hibernate team.

I have already considered

1. SQL update on DTYPE field and
2. delete and re-insert a new entry of the right type... but this all looks like a wrong usage of Hibernate.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to query the "waiter" object casted to a "person" object (assuming person is the parent in your inheritance tree), then cast it a manger, set relevant fields and persist the manger object.